# ASCII converter is showing blank with wrong input - PHP

Tags: php, ascii

I'm trying to convert ASCII to characters with the following script.

```php
<?php
$decencrypt = explode(" ", $_POST['decryptinput']);
for($i=0;$i<=count($decencrypt)-1;$i++){
    echo(chr($decencrypt[$i]));
}
?>
```

It works with text like: `Lorem Ipsum`
 (Encrypted in ASCII)
But when I use input: `for($i=0;$i<=count($decencrypt)-1;$i++){for($i=0;$i<=count($decencrypt)-1;$i++){`
(f.e.)

It won't work and my site just shows blank.


Can someone help me out so every possible input will work?

Notice that the input looks like this: `116 101 115 116 32 116 101 120 116 32 102 111 114 32 115 116 97 99 107 111 118 101 114 102 108 111 119 13 10`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Unclear - you need to clarify: _"But when I use input: `for($i=0;$i<=count($decencrypt)-1;$i++){for($i=0;$i<=count($decencrypt)-1;$i++){` (f.e.) It won't work and my site just shows blank."_

Comment: can you show your form? make sure you use `post` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php    
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$decryptinput = '116 101 115 116 32 116 101 120 116 32 102 111 114 32 115 116 97 99 107 111 118 101 114 102 108 111 119 13 10';
echo $decryptinput.'<br>';
echo asciiDecode($decryptinput);
echo '<br>';
echo asciiEncode("test text for stackoverflow\r\n");


function asciiDecode($iAsciiStr){
    $retStr = '';
    foreach(explode(' ', $iAsciiStr) as $key=>$val){
          $retStr .= chr($val);
    }
    return $retStr;
}

function asciiEncode($iDecStr){
    $retStr = '';
    foreach(str_split($iDecStr) as $key=>$val){
          $retStr .= ord($val).' ';
    }
    return $retStr;
}
```